# Enable script run in web browser using java script codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I designed a web page which contains some javascripts, but when I'm running the page in certain browsers like internet explorer my scripts get blocke and the browsers asks for manual enabling of the script in that browser

I need java script or jquery code for enabling script run in any browser automatically. Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: What type of Java script is it, an applet?

Comment: @Bergi I think he meant JavaScript?

Comment: @Bergi no there is some script for validating a web form in that page

Comment: And no, there will be no possibilty to automatically self-allow a script to run when the browser asks the user to do that, anything else would be a security leak.

Comment: I think this was due to the Internet Explorer security settings. Have you tried to lower them?

Comment: @Bergi yes andrew peacock said that

Comment: @AndrewPeacock: Yes, I think so too, but he didn't wrote it :-)

Comment: @sam: Why does IE block a simple form validating script? Lower your security settings.

Comment: @Bergi  but facebook and another similar sites contain java scripts but they have no problem

Comment: We need a lot more detail of _what_ you're trying to do and _what_ error messages you're getting. So far you've said effectively nothing.

Comment: @sam: so when they're similiar, tell us where the difference is. And note: It's "javascript", no blanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible for a website to turn on JavaScript if it is disabled in the browser.

Design your site with [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) in mind.

---

If, by "certain browsers like internet explorer", you mean "Internet Explorer will not run my code" (as opposed to "Browsers wil JS turned off will not run my code") then you may just need to learn how to write cross-browser compatible code.

Without a specific example of code that does not work (along with the specific error messages you receive), that topic is too broad to cover on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are running the website locally, ie opening the file not serving it from a web server. Try running a local web server or hosting your site on a free online service and as long as the browser doesn't have JavaScript disabled the messages shouldn't show up.