# all sites to run JavaScript setting in asp.net application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a task to show "**all sites to run JavaScript setting**" in my asp.net application like this:

[image]

- we can see this JavaScript settings in Chrome setting but i need to
  show this seetings in my asp.net application.
- I don't have any idea to implement this setting in my page.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got a clue what you're asking here.  You want to replicate a Chrome Setting in your ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Your website isn't going to be able to tell browsers whether or not they can use javascript

Comment: Exactly yes. I need to show that chrome setting in my asp.net application.

Comment: Firstly, as @mituw16 say, you cannot change any setting on a users browser - that would be a massive security risk.  Secondly, it would also assume that every single one of your users is using Chrome.  I'm not sure you know what you're asking for here

Comment: Browser is not an issue but like that all browser having that JavaScript enabled setting. I need to implement that in my asp.net application.

Comment: @dinesh.k You simply are not going to be able to do anything on your site to make browsers enable javascript. That is impossible. The best thing you can do is implement something like Brandon mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you can read that setting directly or not.

You'd probably be better off using `<noscript>` tags. Anything within a noscript tag will display if the browser is unable to use javascript.

Something like

```
<noscript>
   You must have javascript enabled to view this web page. Please enable it 
   in your browser settings.
</noscript>
```

Try it with StackOverflow. Disable javascript and reload this page and you'll see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is not seem to be possible:

See the similar post:

[Enable script run in web browser using java script codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399391/enable-script-run-in-web-browser-using-java-script-codes)

Comment: If it is a replication, please comment under the original question - once you have enough reputation you will be able to request to close the question yourself

Comment: @^ Sure I respect your suggestion :).